# Can Linux kernel support RSTP (802.1w)?

Tags: linux, networking, kernel, stp, rstp

Last week, I ran Spanning Tree Protocol (STP) in Linux kernel successfully.

Now, I am trying to support Rapid Spanning Tree Protocol (RSTP) in Linux kernel.

I also found out some solutions in user space such as mstp (https://github.com/mstpd/mstpd). However, I want to find a solution in the kernel.

I searched patch from internet but I can't find anything. Is there any limitation that Linux kernel is not able to support RSTP?

Answer (score 1):

There was a daemon implementation of RSTP by Stephen Hemminger (https://github.com/shemminger/RSTP), but he has stated that it is EOL (last commit was 2011).

The kernel only implements 802.1D-1998 STP, and the kernel documentation on bridging links to docs that state "STP should be in user space" :)

Your best bet is the mstpd daemon.